# raphael pie chart error?

Tags: javascript, raphael, pie-chart

i try to add grahael pie chart in my web site using same code from graphael site

gRaphaël Static Pie Chart

```
    <script src="http://raphaeljs.com/raphael.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="g.raphael.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="g.pie.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        window.onload = function () {
            var r = Raphael("holder");
            r.g.txtattr.font = "12px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif";

            r.g.text(320, 70, "Static Pie Chart").attr({"font-size": 20});

            r.g.piechart(320, 240, 150, [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10]);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body class="raphael" id="g.raphael.dmitry.baranovskiy.com">
    <div id="holder"></div>

    <p>
        Demo of <a href="http://g.raphaeljs.com/">gRaphaël</a> JavaScript library.
    </p>
</body>
```

But im not getting the chart and on firebug im getting error like Raphael not defined ?

Comment: Any Suggestion ? i really cant find any solutions ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="http://raphaeljs.com/raphael.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="g.raphael.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="g.pie.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

You are loading one script from a remote site and the others locally. Are you sure you actually have `g.raphael.js` and `g.pie.js` in the same folder as your html file?